# The distribution of the sample mean of poisson distribution.

Tags: probability, statistics

Given iid $X_1,\ldots,X_n\sim\operatorname{Poisson}(\lambda)$. Let $\bar X$ denote the sample mean. I am trying to prove that 
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} P(\bar X\neq \lambda)=0.
$$
I know the summation of poisson distribution is still poisson. But average by $n$ it will give an non-integer distribution...

Any help is really welcome!

Comment: Your statement is false, because $\overline{X}$ will always be rational, but $\lambda$ could be irrational. Perhaps you want to prove that $P(\overline{X} \to \lambda)=1$ (i.e. the strong law of large numbers in the Poisson case).

Comment: @Ian I see. You are right!